# Chrome Extension: Running Javascript Through Multiple Pages?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a google chrome extension that runs javascript when a particular site is accessed (i.e. images.myDomain.com/*). Once the javascript is injected, it then triggers a button click to go to a new page (i.e. frames.myDomain.com/*). The problem is once this new page loads, I want to continue running more javascript, but I know I can't.

Should I build 2 separate extensions? One that reacts to images.myDomain.com and another that reacts to frames.myDomain.com, or is there a simple way of doing this with one extension? Like maybe having two separate js files?

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: you can add an event to `chrome.tabs.onUpdated`, see what domain the tab is on, then execute code.

Comment: Hi Kenny! Thanks for your help. Would that work if I'm having all this occur in the same tab (no new tabs)?

Comment: it should. I didn't try it, but `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` sounds like it would trigger every time a tab (or the tab) is updated

Comment: Yes, it should work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple content_script declarations in your manifest file. Something like this:

```
"content_scripts": [
    {"matches": ["http://images.myDomain.com/*"], "js": ["some_script.js"]},
    {"matches": ["http://frames.myDomain.com/*"], "js": ["some_other_script.js"]}
],
```

Comment: Thanks Jude! Exactly what I was looking for! Super simple and quick!